# XNA 4.0 weird color error

Tags: colors, xna-4.0, light

I am having problems drawing a terrain with XNA, specifically with colors (It happens with VertexPositionColorNormal and with VertexPositionTextureNormal). My code is following:

```
public BasicEffect GetEffectForColoredTerrain()
{
    this.coloredTerrainEffect.EnableDefaultLighting();
    this.coloredTerrainEffect.SpecularPower = 0.01f; //Power of the light
    this.coloredTerrainEffect.AmbientLightColor = new Vector3(0.1f, 0.1f, 0.1f); //Color of the light when it reflects on a surface
    this.coloredTerrainEffect.EmissiveColor = new Vector3(1, 0, 0);
    this.coloredTerrainEffect.DirectionalLight0.Enabled = true; //Enable directional light
    this.coloredTerrainEffect.DirectionalLight0.DiffuseColor = (new Vector3(0.2f, 0.2f, 0.2f)); //Diffuse color
    this.coloredTerrainEffect.DirectionalLight0.SpecularColor = (new Vector3(0.2f, 0.2f, 0.2f)); //Specular color
    this.coloredTerrainEffect.DirectionalLight0.Direction = Vector3.Normalize(new Vector3(1, -1f, 1)); //Direction where the light comes from.
    this.coloredTerrainEffect.View = Camera.GetInstance().GetViewMatrix();
    this.coloredTerrainEffect.Projection = Camera.GetInstance().GetProjectionMatrix();
    this.coloredTerrainEffect.Alpha = (float)((float)Configuration.GetInstance().TerrainOpacity / (float)100);
    this.coloredTerrainEffect.VertexColorEnabled = true;

    return this.coloredTerrainEffect;
}
```

And this code for drawing terrain:

```
RasterizerState rs = new RasterizerState();
rs.CullMode = CullMode.None;
WorldContent.CommonGraphicsDevice.RasterizerState = rs;
//Restore things that SpriteBatch can have overriden
WorldContent.CommonGraphicsDevice.BlendState = BlendState.AlphaBlend;
WorldContent.CommonGraphicsDevice.DepthStencilState = DepthStencilState.Default;
WorldContent.CommonGraphicsDevice.SamplerStates[0] = SamplerState.LinearClamp;

BasicEffect shader = ShadersHandler.GetInstance().GetEffectForColoredTerrain();
foreach (EffectPass pass in shader.CurrentTechnique.Passes)
{
    pass.Apply();
    WorldContent.CommonGraphicsDevice.Indices = indexBufferVertices;
    WorldContent.CommonGraphicsDevice.SetVertexBuffer(vertexBufferVertices);
    WorldContent.CommonGraphicsDevice.DrawIndexedPrimitives(PrimitiveType.TriangleList, 0, 0, vertexPositionColorNormalList.Length, 0, indicesVertices.Length / 3);
}
```

However, the result is really weird, as you can see in the following images:

[Terrain laterally](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/805/terrainlateral.png/)

[Terrain bottom](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/254/terrainbottom.png/)

Color is a gradient from Yellow to white (yellow up, white down). However, if I use the effects file from Riemers tutorial (effects.fx from 3D Series 1), everything is correct, as you can see here:

[Terrain good laterally](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/441/terraingoodlateral.png/)

[Terrain good bottom](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/35/terrainggoodbottom.png/)

If you wish, you can see the effect code here: [Effects file](http://pastebin.com/a2A8J33W)

So **QUESTION**: Does anyone knows what is happening here with BasicEffect? I would like to use the Riemers file (everything seems correct with it), but I need to use transparency and the BasicEffect object provides me alpha property, which is perfect for what I am looking for.

PD: The same problem happens with textured terrain, using VertexPositionNormalTexture

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the images, the discoloration appears to be a very nice circle, as from a directional light. I would try removing the DirectionalLight0 property settings you are using in the BasicEffect example and see if that corrects the discoloration.

Comment: Yes, if I remove the DirectionalLight0 property then the terrain is colored correctly, but I don't want an homogeneous color, but depending on a light...

Comment: Try using the Emmisive Color to affect the coloration of the terrain.